# Selenium: Can I combine several commands into one command to be referenced by other tests without coding

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm currently evaluating Selenium and it seems I'll have to perform certain steps in my tests over and over again.  Is there any way to wrap several steps from a selenium test into one single step which can be referenced by other tests?

It seems that this can be done with with custom coding [as mentioned at in the UI-Element documentation](http://svn.openqa.org/fisheye/browse/~raw,r=trunk/selenium/trunk/src/main/resources/core/scripts/ui-doc.html), but I'd prefer to use the IDE if possible.

Thanks,

Adrian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is a way. I added it to my blog article comparing [Selenium to Coded UI](https://devermind.wordpress.com/2010/05/06/selenium-vs-coded-ui-my-perspective/)

Comment: link's dead -- can you elaborate on this? would love to know more.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is to use Rollups (as mentioned in the UI-Element documentation) to combine several commands into a single command. Once rollups are written you can use them in Selenium IDE.

Comment: Actually there is a workaround, I described it here: http://devermind.com/testing/selenium-vs-coded-ui-my-perspective/